# REST service in redis

Tags: redis

I'm new to redis. Trying to find out if we can build a REST api for redis cache elements so that they can be consumed by different clients (node, c# etc) Is it possible to do it? If so, can I get some guidance ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis)** which will give you **rest oriented client** which will wrap around redis. As it is REST oriented you can connect major through all other microservices written in different languages.

It supports major feature.

Comment: How easy is it to push\store large nested objects using webdis? Can we get any samples on how to implement it?

Comment: Go to the github page of webdis. It will tell you about the implementation and what to and not to expect from it.